# How to test my php script for sql injection and prevent it

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have input values like user can upload a photo, enter a username, password...etc

I want to test the SQL injection by myself and I want some way to prevent it.

I am using MySQL I know some of you will say use PDO or MySqli BUT at this time I am still having Mysql as database.

Thank You!

Comment: i sow this one @JohnConde BUT pleas read my question good 
i want you to tell me HOW do i inject it !

Comment: Just because you are using a MySQL database doesn't mean you can't use PDO or MySQLi extensions on the client side.

Comment: @YoussefSubehi You can look into penetration testing services or tools to "attack" your application with all sorts of exploits - SQL injection, XSS, CSRF, etc.

Comment: There are [testing tools](http://sqlmap.org/) that will find all kinds of absolutely horrifying things. Be very careful to test only a development copy as you might accidentally trash your production system if it's full of holes.

Comment: PDO and MySQLi are just different ways to connect to MySQL Database, you don't need to change your database.

Comment: Why is this is perfectly reasonable question getting downvoted? There seems to be a nasty-gang on StackOverflow who get pleasure from attacking newbies.

Comment: i don't know why it's down and i don't care im here to ask and learn i don't care about other response down or up im here for answer and ger the answer.@NigelAlderton thank you but there is a lot of nasty-gang as u said

Answer (score 2):

Many documentation on google. See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2226755

Try putting `'` or `"` in your input, if you've an error it's a sql injection.

[Understanding SQL Injection](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/sql_injection.html)

Comment: That's a very superficial test as there are ways of sneaking around that using UTF-8. Someone who's used `addslashes` might think they're safe, but couldn't be more wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When testing an application of this sort, put values like this in every field:

```
<div style="background:red">It's Buggy</div>
```

If that isn't inserted correctly, you'll have errors. If it is inserted correctly and rendered as unescaped HTML you'll know immediately.

This applies to every single parameter that can come in via `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Writing with `mysql_query` is hazardous at the best of times, and downright reckless if you're not extremely careful. PDO works well with MySQL and [doesn't take that long to learn if you follow a good tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

You should be writing queries like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)
```

The `?` is a data placeholder that you can safely bind against.

A better approach is to use something like [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) to provide a proper database layer. This makes your code much more readable and portable between MySQL and other databases.

Comment: Or, better yet, call yourself `Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--` and see what happens

Comment: I agree, [Bobby's Table](http://bobby-tables.com) is my favorite test.

Comment: `Bobby's "Table"` would catch both kinds of quotes.

Comment: if you need to preserve the data exactly as it is entered, base64 encode it before adding it to the db. then decode when you want to display it

Comment: @IzzyKiefer Absolutely not. Do not do this.

Comment: @tadman can you elaborate please? why not?

Comment: @IzzyKiefer It's completely pointless if you **use placeholder values**. At no point should you be interpolating and risking SQL injection bugs.

Comment: @tadman i got you. thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

you can inject in SQl with code like
    `anything' OR 'x'='x`
you can easily prevent this, just google "sql injection example(s)" and see for yourself

Comment: An answer that says "Google it" is not really an answer at all.

Comment: if you think i'm going to place all sql injections i know here, you're wrong. He asks for examples, i gave him one and an instruction to learn more of them, fair enough i suppose

Answer (score 0):

Injection techniques vary based on the use case. As an example for username/password checks, given this SQL:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE name = "$_POST['name']"
AND password = "$_POST['pass']";
```

...in this case, passing a simple `" OR "" = "` for the `POST`ed password field would yield this:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE name = ""
AND password = ""
OR "" = "";
```

...and **BAM**! There are `user_id` results where in reality there aren't supposed to be.

This is just one isolated case. I'd suggest looking into using `PDO` as your database driver to do injection checking for you!

Comment: Also, [the link suggested](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) by @tadman is a great resource... just take the time to learn PDO. It'll save you _tons_ of time compared to your entire system being hacked and going down.